# python program in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, excel

I have been working on a problem and currently in a fix. The problem is that I need to transfer data currently in an excel sheet to MySQL database. So far I have been able to get the file on the server (running Django 1.6) and only thing that gets in the database is the address of the file.

Also, I have a program that can post data from the excel sheet to the database, however this needs to be done manually and every time the file is uploaded.

As I see this, one way of solving this is to trigger the program as soon as the file upload is complete on the server, but I am not able to figure out how to this. Also suggest any other way to get the data transferred from excel file to MySQL database.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trigger the program in the `upload_file` function in Django. You can do it just before end of this function. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/) is instruction for you.